# Using DataTrigger on Validation.ErrorTemplate property

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set up different styling for a border around a textbox for both errors and warnings. Currently I am able to get the default error styling color to show but implementing warnings with DataTrigger doesn't seem to update the styling on the border. The DataTrigger is supposed to be bound to a bool value in an object in (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContext outside of Windows.Resources.

```
 <Style x:Name="ErrTemplate" x:Key="ErrTemplate">
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
          <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Uid="ControlWithErrors" Name="ControlWithErrors>
                         <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
                    </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent.IsWarning, ElementName="ControlWithErrors}" Value="true">
                              <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                         </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
     <Setter>
</Style>
```

And the element outside of Windows.Resources that has notification on validation errors whenever an invalid name is word is typed

```
<TextBox
     x:Uid="EmailName"
     x:Name="EmailName"
     Text="{Binding EmailName, Mode="TwoWay", NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, UpdateSourcetrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     Style="{DynamicResource ErrTemplate}"/>
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is that you set `BorderBrush="Red"` as local value. Set it in a style and it should then work, if the binding is correct.
See [Dependency property value precedence (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-6.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
<Style x:Name="ErrTemplate" x:Key="ErrTemplate">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Uid="ControlWithErrors" Name="ControlWithErrors">
                    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                    </Border>
                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [0].ErrorContent.IsWarning}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This didn’t work unfortunately

Comment: Have you removed `BorderBrush="Red"`?

Comment: Yes only have that property on the setter like in your code

Comment: The trigger binding is also wrong, it should be `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [0].ErrorContent.IsWarning}" Value="true">`. I'll update the answer.